# Float primitive to return null if possible or a specific value if the value is null in the DB

Tags: java, jpa

So basically as the title mentions this is what I'm trying to do, I have this column defined

```
@Column(name="MATCH_SCORE", columnDefinition="NUMBER(10,4) default '-1.0000'")
private float matchScore;
```

so what I was expecting is that value to return with -1 if it's null in the DB, however, I still get it as 0 which is an issue because I have to take a specific action if the value is zero while I don't do it in case the value is null, unfortunately, I can't do any change the DB, so I'll have to do it from the app side.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem here might be that primitive `float` cannot be `null`.  Instead, you could use `Float`, but a better choice to map a `NUMBER` (exact precision) column would be `BigDecimal`.  Try this version:

```
@Column(name="MATCH_SCORE", columnDefinition="NUMBER(10,4) default -1.0000")
private BigDecimal matchScore;
```

Also note that the purpose of a column's default value is that if an insert happens and no value (or `NULL`) is specified for that column, then the database will use that default value instead.  Default values don't really have anything to do with what happens when you select; whatever value is in the column for that record will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the primitive type float, instead of the nullable BigDecimal that also has no rounding problems, do

```
@Column(name="MATCH_SCORE", columnDefinition="NUMBER(10,4)")
private Float matchScoreRaw;

@Transient
public float getMatchScore() {
    return matchScoreRaw == null ? Float.NaN : matchScoreRaw;
}

@Deprecated
public Float getMatchScoreRaw() {
    return matchScoreRaw == null ? Float.NaN : matchScoreRaw; // Bad.
}
```

Representing dataabase NULL as not-a-number. A getter for the raw value might help "repairing" the database, though NULL might be better, as I do not know how NaN is represented in the database, and whether it can be read again.

*Best would be to convert all NULL entries to something and not use two fields.*